# Creating error with anonymous function

Tags: javascript, error-handling, anonymous-function

Creating custom errors in JavaScript can be done in this way:

```
function err(message) {
    this.name = "MyError";
    this.message = "Some message";
}
err.prototype = Error.prototype;

throw new err();        //(x) MyError: Some message
```

However I'm not a big fan of creating one-time-use functions. So I tried to create an error with an anonymous function:

```
throw new (function(){
    this.name = "MyError";
    this.message = "Some message";
    arguments.callee.prototype = Error.prototype;
})();                   //(x) [object Object]
```

[image]

They both are basically the same thing. However, the error message this code generated looks like `[object Object]` with the keys `message` and `name` inside (which is correct but the browser isn't showing my custom error name and message.)

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: I get `MyError: Some message`

Comment: What's displayed in the console depends entirely on what browser you're using, and the browser may choose to format it in whatever way it sees fit.

Comment: @p.s.w.g - But why are they causing different behaviors if they are the same?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 What *should be* the exact same data structure in JavaScript may be displayed differently on the console depending on how several factors, including optimizations made by the browser's JS engine. And occasionally, the exact same code can sometimes produce different console outputs under different circumstances. I've seen this many times in Chrome.

Comment: Basically, unless you're creating code to specifically target a single browser (e.g. a browser plug-in) you're probably better off thinking of the console as 'magic' and not making any assumptions as to how it will be displayed or trying to tailor the code to be 'console-friendly'. After all, it's not likely to behave exactly the same way in any other browser, and for any single browser, the behavior *could* change in the next software update.